# In-App Purchase - How to determine if a purchase has already been made?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Why it's so hard to find out how to do this is beyond me - so maybe I am trying to do this the wrong way - who knows - well hopefully one of you, lol.

I have a button that says 'Purchase' (for a non-consumable).  If the purchase is successful then update NSUserDefaults purchased = YES and the button is removed.  All good up to here.

Now when the user deletes the app and wants to reinstall or install on a new device then what I would like to show, in these cases, in place of the 'Purchase' button is a 'Restore' button. 'Restore' button would be clicked and restoreCompletedTransactions would be called.  Seems logical to me - user doesn't want to see a 'Purchase' button - they have purchased already.

Problem is NSUserDefaults purchased = YES will not be available on re-install or new install.  So my question is how do I determine if the app has been purchased before so I can either display a 'Purchase' button or a 'Restore' button.  Is there a way to determine if this in-app purchase has already been made by the user?

Thanks in advance, Byron.

Comment: try to use the `-restoreCompletedTransactions` of `SKPaymentQueue` method for it. it will provide you the purchased products, and you can show the _Restore_ button until the user restores the purchases on the new device.

Comment: @holex So on a re-install or an install on another device of the app  I will need to call restoreCompletedTransactions so I can determine if the 'Restore' button should be shown. (1)However if the user has not previously made the in-app purchase then I need to catch that case. I can do that in paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: What will the SKPaymentTransaction.transactionState be if there has been no previous transaction? (2) Will restoreCompletedTransactions ask the user to enter their details? Wouldn't want that to happen till the 'Restore' button is tapped.

Comment: if the _iTunes Account_ is set on the device properly, the restore procedure won't ask the user's details. If there is no _iTunes Account_ had been set on device, the standard procedure asks him/her about it. after the first restoring you can save a key/value pair (`purchased` = `YES`) in the `NSUserDefaults`, and then you can check it every time for showing/hiding of the _Restore_ button. after the first restoring you won't need the _Restore_ button anymore, your application will be updated of the purchased products, and the next purchase can happen normally in the further.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to transfer state from one app install to another app install in the future. You might be able to abuse the keychain for this, but you shouldn't.

Just show "Purchase" all the times. On iOS that's the standard way of handling this situation. People are used to see a purchase button even if they have purchased before, they will understand what that means. Of course you still need a restore button somewhere.

Depending on the kind of store you use you have two options to place the restore button.

If you have a store like interface, e.g. a tableView which lists all your products, put a "Restore Purchase" cell at the end of your tableView. Here is the interface of PCalc Lite as an example:

[image]

If you don't have a store like interface, put a button in the settings section of your app. That's how Disco Zoo does it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a backend server that the app interrogates to determine if the user has purchased by way of signing into an account on the device. Apple will require you to have some sort of checking facility for the reasons you pointed out...users should not have to re purchase on new device or other devices they might own. You must make the account sign up optional to the user, again Apple will require this.

Comment: Could - but given that this in-app purchase just unlocks functionality that is already present in the app (nothing is downloaded) this seems like a heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question and you probably solved it, but I had a similar problem in terms of designing a user friendly interface for the purchase mechanism and found a solution like this:

```
-(IBAction) purchase
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:<# A brief explanation #>
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Restore",@"Purchase", nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    alert.tag = _IAPTAG;
    [alert show];
}
```

then in the alert view delegate function:

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == _IAPTAG)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            //cancel
        }
        else if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            //restore
        }
        else if(buttonIndex == 2)
        {
            //purchase
        }
    }
}
```

So the restore option will restore and the purchase will purchase, eventually. If the user is buying for the first time, then s/he won't be worried about buying twice anyway. If the user bought before and is installing the app on another device, then s/he will know that the purchase button will give the option to restore.

Comment: I don't see how this is user friendly. People who have not purchased will see this alert more often, and have to answer a useless alert. Just put a restore button in your settings, or if you have a shop like interface (e.g. a tableview) make the bottom cell a "restore purchases" button. That's the standard way of handling this, it's used in countless apps.

Comment: additionally: iOS users don't expect the purchase restoring functionality under the "buy" button, because nobody does that on iOS. Btw. if you purchase a non consumable again it will be restored automatically. So your alert is even more superfluous. Is your app live in the store? Because I doubt that Apple would allow functionality like this.

Comment: The original question is finding a way to achieve this without adding the extra restore button. Also, the standard way has an extra view and an extra restore button with the extra purchase buttons for each item. I know it's standard and I'm not challenging it. But if you are comparing in terms of extra navigation, there is no difference and In my humble experience as a user, it's actually less with just an alert view.

Comment: additionally: yes, you can do this automatically but to achieve that you want to make sure the user is logged in. I don't see how it's user friendly to show a log in alert without a single line of explanation.

Comment: Is your app with the restore/purchase alert live in the App Store? I have doubts that Apple would allow this. They require you to have a visible "restore purchases" button somewhere in your app.

Comment: Not yet. After I submit I'll tell the result but I believe that it should work because the discussion here is about semantics. Renaming the button as 'Unlock Premium Features' for instance, will solve the restore-after-buy problem and it is completely equivalent with displaying a new view with the purchase and restore buttons.

Comment: sorry to keep this turning into a thread but last message: as I said I'd report; the application is accepted with an alert view purchase dialog.