# In-App Purchase restore all - prevent individual purchase

Tags: xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I've implemented in app purchasing on my app and it works fine. I followed Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial to get it all working. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

The only problem I have is that I created a product identifier on iTunes connect with a .All name at the end. If a user decides to buy all the apps options. It works, and all the options are unlocked with the code I wrote, but there is one situation I can't seem to get around.

If a user has used the purchase all option, then has to reload the game. As expected all the NSuserdefaults have been wiped and all the in app purchase options now appear locked again. Selecting one of the options brings up the same window the user first saw when they purchased all options previously. It asks them if they would like to buy the one option they selected or buy all. Now, if the user accidentally decides to select the buy individual item and not use the restore or buy all buttons, then because that individual item was not purchased in the first place, the sale goes through for the purchase of the individual item. Even though they purchased the All option originally.

My question is how can I check for the purchase of the all option when the user defaults that were used to persist the purchase have been cleared. Is there a way to set the other iTunes connect products to a purchased state if the user buys the All product? or is there a better way of doing this other than having a separate All product on iTunes connect?

Comment: What system version are you working with? And what product types?

Comment: I'm working with Xcode 5, iOS 6 and up and the products are Non consumables. Purchases just trigger my code to unlock features.

Comment: I just had a read through this and was thinking it might be an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667456/in-app-purchase-how-to-determine-if-a-purchase-has-already-been-made It seems like the responses suggest using restoreCompletedTransactions to provide purchase then go fro there, but I'm not sure where to call that from.

Comment: A receipt refresh should work on iOS7, but a restore would be a good bet in general. Just have to convince the user they should do a restore before attempting any purchase.

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that. If the user sees that a restore is about to happen, they might wonder whats going on, but I guess I could pop up a message informing them.

Comment: I just had a look at the SKReceiptRefreshRequest which is available only in iOS7. This is my first app, and its only for the iPad, I'm thinking that I shouldn't even build for iOS6. Especially since these stats seem to indicate over 82% of iPads use iOS7 - http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/